# Questions on general HPC Theory-- Speedup, Efficiency and the like

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, hpc

I am just now learning about speedup and optimal efficiency and after reviewing some notes I have a few questions I hope I can get help with!  This is all in terms of theory not practice just to bear in mind.  So thanks in advance!

1)  If I have the notation T(n,p) it is my understanding that it refers to the time needed to compute a job of n size on p processors, so if I know that,

T(n,n^2) = sqrt(n) and T(n,n) = n how would I determine which algorithm runs faster for a range of p?  Could I simply set the p on one of the algorithms equal to the other one and take the smallest time?  Is there a way to compute this over a range of p's ?

2) What does it mean to be optimally efficient?  If I know the execution times for the serial algorithm and parallel algorithm as functions of n and p say (n^2 and n^2/p + p*n respectively) how would I calculate the max p to satisfy the requirement to be optimally efficient?

3) I'm a little fuzzy on complexity...What exactly is the big Theta getting at?  For the case of Θ(n^2) in respect to the serial algorithm and Θ(n^2/p + (n/sqrt(p))*log(⁡p)) how can I determine the max p as a function of n to obtain maximum possible efficiency?  Can the Theta guy cancel out if I find the speedup S(p) = serial/parallel and then just calculate the max p for efficiency using E(p) = S(p)/p formula ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Or any pointers in the right direction Thanks!

Comment: Hi, im not hugely good at maths but I know that the big Theta is known as Big O notation, some sorting algorithms have this level of efficiency, try googling Big O notation for some better explanations. It also might be worth looking into some sorting algorithms to see how they come up with this formula

Comment: Okay thanks! I took a look at it, it gave a little bit of direction.  I'm still just a bit confused on how to use the information I have.